# Overflowing border with gradient background

Tags: css

I have a block (container) with gradient as background color. The container have a border, and inside it, i have a text that I want to overflow part of a border and have the same background color. Now I have something like this:

[image: first image]

But I want to achieve something like this:

[image: second image]

To overflow some border area but still having the gradient background color, because if I add background color to the block of text, it still different from the gradient effect.

**EDIT**: I'd like to achieve something like this:

[image: third image]

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Here is an example of the code https://jsfiddle.net/narozsfh/10/

Comment: I think that would only be possible if that gradient was actually applied as a `fixed` background - otherwise, you won’t be able to match position and size between the two (unless you want to involve JavaScript and do rather complex calculations.) I guess I’d try to emulate the top border using the approach of https://css-tricks.com/line-on-sides-headers/ - but in combination with a border-radius even that would probably require additions to the HTML to have additional elements to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
body {
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.25);
}
    .container {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        margin: 50px;
        background-color: purple;

        position: relative;
        border: 3px solid black;
        border-radius: 15px;
    }
        .float-text {
            position: absolute;
            top: -15px;
            right: 20px;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            background-color: #fff2ac;
            background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red 0%, orange 100%); /* maybe you mentioning gradient you meant like this? */
            text-transform: uppercase;      
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="float-text">
        Text
    </div>
</div>
```

### Edit

You mention a gradient, maybe you mean like this? (I added the gradient behind the the text box). If not - remove the background-image gradient if you just want solid colour.

Answer (score 0):

According to your JSFiddle code, I think the following code will help you.

```css
.gradient-box {
    background-image: linear-gradient(white, grey);
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.text {
margin-top:-20px;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: #a9b0a9;
  color: #429778;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient-box">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text"> <span class="highlight"> TEXT </span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It will not work because the background color of the text does not match the gradient background color and visually they arre different. I just edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You're wanting something like this:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
body {
    background-color: #FBBFBF;
}
    .container {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        margin: 50px;
        background-color: #FBBFBF;

        position: relative;
        border: 3px solid black;
        border-radius: 15px;
    }
        .float-text {
            position: absolute;
            top: -15px;
            right: 20px;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            background-color: #FBBFBF;
            /* background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red 0%, orange 100%); maybe you mentioning gradient you meant like this? */
            text-transform: uppercase;      
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="float-text">
        Text
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** With transparent BG. Think this is only possible with square borders...

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red 0%, orange 100%);
}
    .container {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        margin: 50px;

        position: relative;
        border-top: 0;
        border-left: 2px solid black;
        border-right: 2px solid black;
        border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    }
        .top-border {
            width: calc(100% - 100px);
            height: 2px;
            background-color: black;
            position: absolute;
            top: -1px;
            left: -1px;
        }
        .top-border-end {
            width: 20px;
            height: 2px;
            background-color: black;
            position: absolute;
            top: -1px;
            right: -1px;
        }
        .float-text {
            width: 80px;
            position: absolute;
            top: -15px;
            right: 20px;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            background-color: transparent;
            /* background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red 0%, orange 100%); maybe you mentioning gradient you meant like this? */
            text-transform: uppercase;  
            text-align: center; 
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="top-border"></div>
    <div class="float-text">
        Text
    </div>
    <div class="top-border-end"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I've edited my question. I just want the background color of floating text to be the same as the gradient background, to be like transparent, but overflowing the borders

Comment: Im your case the background color is the same ,so its easier to achieve that. But in my case the background color is a gradient effect, so i dont know how to make the backgrounds match.